# TYPO3 9.5 - Problems with new Routing Enhancers

Tags: routes, typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

i'm trying to setup the new speaking URL routing for an extbase extension. but absolutly nothing happens with the details links in frontend.

here is my yaml site config code (the NewsPlugin config is working, but CardealerPlugin does not):

```
routeEnhancers:
  NewsPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages: [92,93]
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/{news_title}', _controller: 'News::detail', _arguments: {'news_title': 'news'} }
    defaultController: 'News::detail'
    aspects:
      news_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_news_domain_model_news'
        routeFieldName: 'title'
        routeValuePrefix: '/'
  CardealerPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages: [84,90]
    extension: Cardealer
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/{model_description}', _controller: 'Cardealer::show', _arguments: {'model_description': ' car'} }
    defaultController: 'Cardealer::show'
    aspects:
      model_description:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_cardealer_domain_model_car'
        routeFieldName: 'model_description'
        routeValuePrefix: '/'
```

extTables.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'Cardealer',
    'Pi1',
    'Cardealer'
);
```

**can anybody help please?**

Comment: EXT:cardealer is unknown, probable an own TYPO3 extension. Did you ensure your configured values matches the extension? Fx: plugin name 'Pi1' and controller name 'Cardealer'?

Comment: I think the values are correct. I've added code from extTables.php

Comment: I do not know if this is the reason, but maybe its the extra space in this part: {'model_description': ' car'}

Comment: Another reason could be the place where you register your plugin. I do this in Configuration/TCA/Override/tt_content.php in my Extension and *not* in extTables.php. Additionally I add the Vendor in Front of the extension name like this: \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
  'VENDOR.extensionkey',
  'Pi1',
  'my plugin'
 );

Comment: @AlexanderGrein: thanks for your answer. I have created the Overides files and set the Namespace in registerPlugin(). But it has no effect :-(
How did you build the links to the details views? It seem not possible with the <f:link.action action="show" controller="Cardealer" pageUid="{settings.pid.details}" arguments="{car:car}">. I suspect this, because if I use an <f:link.action> in the News List Template, the links also not resolved as Speaking URL.

Comment: and the empty space in ' car' was also removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**After almost a week I found a solution!**

a) The records of my extension have now the new slug TCA field, which generates unique URL segments.

```
'slug' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'URL Segment',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'slug',
        'prependSlash' => true,
        'generatorOptions' => [
            'fields' => ['title'],
            'prefixParentPageSlug' => true,
        ],
        'fallbackCharacter' => '-',
        'eval' => 'uniqueInSite',
    ],
],
```

b) My YAML Config:

```
routeEnhancers:
  CardealerPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages: [86]
    extension: Cardealer
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/{uid_var}'
        _controller: 'Standard::show'
        _arguments:
          uid_var: car
    defaultController: 'Standard::list'
    aspects:
      uid_var:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_cardealer_domain_model_car'
        routeFieldName: 'slug'
```

c) The fluid link

```
<f:link.action action="show" controller="Standard" pageUid="{settings.pid.details}" arguments="{car: '{car.uid}'}">
```

Comment: Great answer. As an addition to this. If you only use an simple content element extension the yaml property plugin must be plugin: '' and the fluid link must have extensionName="MyExtension". Also i have a FE-Error if TCA prependSlash + prefixParentPageSlug is true.

Answer (score 4):

There's currently a bug https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87542 which breaks routes for non-default plugin controllers if the "skipDefaultArguments" feature is enabled for your plugin in TypoScript Setup.

So for the time being, make sure that `skipDefaultArguments`  is **not active** in your extension TypoScript configuration:

```
plugin.tx_myextension {
    features {
        skipDefaultArguments = 0
    }
}
```

Also, check if the default TypoScript setup of the extension is included in your TypoScript template.

Comment: this was not the reason. my problem is solved. see the first answer

Comment: sure, but sine people will run into the same problem and find this via google, this answer may solve their problem, like it did for me.